# Unable to mount Secondary Harddrive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd, gparted, ext4

My primary hard drive is a SSD and is boot essential drive. I have a 1.5 TB hard drive (HDD) in my computer which is partitioned: 440 GB for my Ubuntu as ext4. Today when I booted up I got an error.
[image]

I chose to skip the mounting.

---

Then as soon as I logged in an error message pops up. (see image A)

---

Then I went to gparted to see whats up.

[image]

I am not sure what the mount point is supposed to like like but everything else is fine.

---

Then I got to *Disks* And I get another error. (See Image B)
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the content of your `/etc/fstab` and what the command `sudo fdisk -l` returns?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I am not sure why its fixed but it works now. I had to go to *Disks* > *Edit Mount Options* > turn on *Automatic Mount Options*

[image]